# Calculate time to next xx:x7

Tags: php, date

I've frequently used `strtotime("next time")` to get the time to the next instance of a daily event, but what about shorter intervals?

Something happens every time the units digit of the minutes is 7 (`00:07`, `00:17`, `00:27` and so on in 10-minute intervals)

So given the current time, how do I go about getting the time to the next one?

Currently the best I can come up with is `strtotime(substr(date("Y-m-d H:i"),0,-1)."7")`, but it seems kind of dirty and doesn't even work for times past xx:x7 and before xx:x0. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seconding the usage of `DateTime`:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime('2013-01-01 16:54:11');
for($qq = 0; $qq < 10; ++$qq) { // loop to test all minute remainders
    $dt->modify('+1 minute +3seconds'); // seconds just for show
    $min = +$dt->format('i'); // current minutes
    $sec = +$dt->format('s'); // current seconds
    $r10 = $min % 10;
    // if it's hh:27 now, this will result in hh:37, change >= to > if that forwarding is not needed
    if($r10 >= 7) {
        $deltaMin = 17 - $r10;
    } else {
        $deltaMin = 7 - $r10;
    }
    // time left until next "good" point in time
    $change = sprintf('%+d minutes -%d seconds', $deltaMin, $sec);
    $new = clone($dt);
    $new->modify($change);
    printf("%s\t %s\n%s\n--\n", $dt->format('r'), $change, $new->format('r'));
}
```

Comment: That's a LOT of code for something that I could simply do with the fix I found for my problem: `(strtotime(substr(date("Y-m-d H:i",DATE),0,-1)."7")-DATE+600)%600` (where `DATE` is a constant holding the current time at the start of the script's execution)

Comment: @Kolink: fair enough, if you document exactly what that thing is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway. I'm going to Accept it because it was well-written and it is a best practice as opposed to my one-line-hack.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there:

```
$now = time() + (date('is')>5700?600:0);
$new = strtotime(substr(date("Y-m-d H:i", $now),0,-1)."7");
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use the [`DateTime::setTime()`](http://php.net/datetime.settime) method, with a little bit of arithmetic.

```
$date = new DateTime('12:34', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

$minute = ceil(($date->format('i') - 7 + 1) / 10) * 10 + 7;
$date->setTime($date->format('G'), $minute, 0);

echo $date->format('H:i'); // 12:37
```

---

An example of using it in a loop, for demonstration purposes:

```
$date = new DateTime('16:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
$period = new DatePeriod($date, new DateInterval('PT1M'), 60);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('H:i => ');

    $minute = ceil(($date->format('i') - 7 + 1) / 10) * 10 + 7;
    $date->setTime($date->format('G'), $minute, 0);

    echo $date->format('H:i'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above outputs something like:

```
16:00 => 16:07
16:01 => 16:07
16:02 => 16:07
16:03 => 16:07
16:04 => 16:07
16:05 => 16:07
16:06 => 16:07
16:07 => 16:17
16:08 => 16:17
16:09 => 16:17
16:10 => 16:17
... removed to save scrolling ...
16:50 => 16:57
16:51 => 16:57
16:52 => 16:57
16:53 => 16:57
16:54 => 16:57
16:55 => 16:57
16:56 => 16:57
16:57 => 17:07
16:58 => 17:07
16:59 => 17:07
17:00 => 17:07
```

[» See this example running online](http://codepad.viper-7.com/onFqkZ)